# Modify propery of an jQuery object instance once it has been instantiated

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the bxSlider plugin for a slideshow like this.

```
ele = $('#slider2').bxSlider({
    minslides: 4,
    maxslides: 4
});
```

I want to change the minslides to 2 if the window size is reduced below 480px so as to make it responsive.
I am trying to bind the window resize property and use it with the variable:

> ele

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(document).width()<=480) w = 2; else w = 4;
    ele.minslides = 2;
    $('#slider2').bxSlider({
    minslides: w,
    maxslides: 4
});
```

});`

but it does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you show the code you used in your attempt?

Comment: You have to do it based on how the plugin allows you to do it (if it even does.) Please include a link to the documentation, and/or read the documentation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Found that bxslider has a reloadSlider() method that can be used for the purpose. Thanks anyways.

```
ele = $('#slider2').bxSlider({
    minslides: 4,
    maxslides: 4
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(document).width()<=480) w = 2; else w = 4;
    ele.reloadSlider();
});
```